# How do I check if my user is an admin in rails even after new http requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My user model has the attributes password, password_confirmation, username, email, and admin.

I'm wondering how exactly do I check whether the currently logged in user is an admin. How would I go about the methods? I've tried if user.admin? on my views, but it seems that doesn't work.

I'm new to rails so any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Why doesn't it seem to work (what happened)? Also, what authentication library are you using (Devise, Oauth, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a "session" hash which persists through the whole session.

Once a user has logged in, you would store the current user's id in the session hash, like so

session[:user_id] = user.id

Now, if you want the current user to be accessible from your controllers and in your views, you can go to apps/controllers/application_controller and make some useful methods...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :current_user, :signed_in?, :is_admin?

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def signed_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def is_admin?
    signed_in? ? current_user.admin : false
  end
end
```

Now in your views you can use "is_admin?" to check if the current user is an admin, use 
"signed_in?" to check if a user is signed in, and "current_user" to access the user object if it exists (if no user is logged in, "current_user" will be nil)

Cheers

Comment: This is really helpful! Also, what does !!current_user do? Specifically, the two !!

Comment: The !! transforms into true or false.  It works like this... if the object is not nil (e.g. if it's a user object) or not false if you use one ! ("not") it becomes false.  Then, using another ! ("not) changes it into true.

Similarly, if it was already nil or false, the first ! ("not") changes it to true, and the second ! ("not") changes it to false.  

So it's a quick and easy way to convert "object / nil" into "true / false".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to consult with this [Devise guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role). It shows how to create a basic user model with help of Devise and how to perform admin checks. And yes, by giving you this link, I strongly encourage you to use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for users and all that stuff ;)

Comment: Side note: it is entirely possible they are indeed using devise (evidence of that *could* be the existence of `password_confirmation` field), we really don't know yet. OP has not provided enough information.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to make an authentication system from scratch to better understand what's going on, SteveTucrzyn's answer helped.